# In Excel, how to have hexadecimal values with spaces in it be converted to decimal?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, hexadecimal

I have the following in a cell:

`00 0A`

I'd like to convert it to the decimal value in excel without removing the spaces and formatting of that cell for readability purposes. How would I do that?

I tried the following:

- `=HEX2DEC(<*cell contents*>)` // But that caused a `#NUM!` error due to the spaces in the original cell.
- `=HEX2DEC(TRIM(<*cell contents*>))` // But that also caused the same `#NUM!` error.

Comment: You need to `SUBSTITUTE()` and use the formula as `=HEX2DEC(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",))`

Comment: *"I'd like to convert it to the decimal value in excel without removing the spaces"* it seems you *do* want to remove them. Confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments above, to parse the spaces in between one needs to use the <kbd>SUBSTITUTE()</kbd> function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=HEX2DEC(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",))
```

---

Also, why one should not use <kbd>TRIM()</kbd> function here because, it removes all spaces from text except for single spaces between words as per **[MSFT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/trim-function-410388fa-c5df-49c6-b16c-9e5630b479f9)** Documentations.

---

Comment: Confirmed working, thank you.

Comment: Yes, I would've done it immediately but SE requires a 10 min. wait from the time of a post.

Comment: @plu glad to know it worked for you =)